# How to iterate through discontiguous for loop in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a scale script where I need to iterate through discontiguous list using for loops.

My requirement is I have two sets of vlans say:

1. no_of_l2_vlans , start_l2_vlan -- This refers to one set and inside each element I do certain operation.
2. no_of_l3_vlans, start_l3_vlan -- This refers to another set and I perform same set of operation as I did for the previous iteration,

I have accomplished that using two for loops for each set linearly but just wondering if there is an effective way of doing it?

```
 for i in range(l2_vlan_start,l2_vlan_start+no_of_l2_vlans):
     <some set of operations>

 for i in range(l3_vlan_start,l3_vlan_start+no_of_l3_vlans):
     <same set of operations>
```

Since the operations are same can I combine these two for loops into a single one?

Please advise .

Comment: [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: do the range of  both the loop are same? if yes then you could do it under one loop

Comment: No. range will differ but the operations inside the for loop is same..

Comment: Can the ranges overlap?

Comment: So are there three possible ranges? One *in the middle* where they overlap and one *on each end* where they don't? In your two loops even though you are performing the **same** operations, are they operating on **different** objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I prefer @0x5453's answer-as-a-comment, here's something a bit more spcialized to your problem & shows how the sausage is made:

```
def mychain(spans):
    for start, no in spans:
        for i in range( start, start+no ):
            yield i

for x in mychain(((l2_vlan_start,no_of_l2_vlans),(l3_vlan_start,no_of_l3_vlans))):
    print(x)
```

Comment: This works perfect. I was able to custom as well inside the for loop which was actually my requirement.